# Data doesn't retrieving with Hibernate max query

Tags: java, hibernate, javadb

I'm using Hibernate 4.2.6 with Java DB 
Here's my
`RegisterationHelper.java`

```
    org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    String uid = std.getUserid();
    System.out.println(uid);
    Query query = session.createQuery("FROM university.Student");
    List<Student> student = query.list();
    for(Iterator it= student.iterator(); it.hasNext();) 
    {
       //some code....
        {
            try 
            {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            int rgstnum=0;
            Query q = session.createQuery("Select max(registrationnumber)from Student");
            List currentRegNo = q.list();
            rgstnum=(Integer)currentRegNo.get(0)+1;
            std.setRegistrationnumber(rgstnum);
            sc.setRegistrationnumber(rgstnum);
            Serializable objID=session.save(std);
            session.saveOrUpdate(sc);
            tx.commit();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
            //priniting sc.getRegistrationnumber() showing null
           //priniting sc.getCurseid() has data
```

and `RegistrationForm.java`

```
    @ManagedBean
    @RequestScoped
public class RegistrationForm {

public String submitAction() {
            RegistrationHelper rghp = new RegistrationHelper();
            Student std = new Student();
            std.setFirstname(getFirstName().toString());
            std.setLastname(getLastName().toString());
            std.setGender(getGender().toString());
            std.setDob(getDateofBirth());
            std.setAddress(getAddress().toString());
            std.setPhone(getContactNumber().toString());
            std.setEmail(getEmailID().toString());
            std.setUserid(getUserID().toString());
            std.setPassword(getPassword().toString());
            Studentcourse sc = new Studentcourse();
            sc.setCourseid(getCourse().toString());
            String msg = rghp.insertStudent(std, sc);
            if(msg.equals("error"))
            {
                setUserIdError("User Id already exist");
                setUserID("");
                return "Registration";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Success";
            }
        }`
```

So I think there is problem only with query `Query q = session.createQuery("Select max(registrationnumber)from Student");` that doesn't retrieving `registrationumber` cause I'm able to store data in `Student` table if removing code regarding `StudentCourse` and other thing is getting `Info:   nested transactions not supported` in sever log.
So please if my query is wrong or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there are problems in the query: the message `nested transactions not supported` refers to the fact that you open the transaction (`session.beginTransaction()`) twice, one at the beginning and then again within the cycle. Try to remove the second.

Comment: Thanks for invaluable time and answer. Will try.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know why they given such code in a book I had problem with prior chapter also. Thank you so much.